# Compile a C extension to Python with a Visual compiler

Tags: python, c, gcc

I have written an extension module for Python in C.

So far I have compiled the module with a gcc compiler. My task is now to compile my code with a MS Visual compiler from the Developer Command Prompt for VS 2015.

To compile my program with the gcc compiler I have used the following commands in the command window:

```
gcc -c  extmodule.c -I/Python34/include
gcc -shared extmodule.o -L/Python34/libs -lpython34 -o ext.dll
```

The project is then build with a setup.py file with the following command:

```
setup.py build -cmingw32
```

This works perfectly fine with the gcc compiler.

Is there anyone who can help me to translate the above lines so I can compile my code with a Visual compiler ?

Comment: Why do you want that? Is gcc compiled module not enough?

Comment: For python 3.4, you will need to use VS2010. If you are using VS2015 you'll need to use python 3.5. Unfortunately it's required to use the same VS version that python itself is compiled with, when compiling extensions.